# jQuery: How do you perform a callback inside an AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function with an AJAX call inside it, I need to be able to call the function and it return true if the AJAX request was successful and false if not.

I know the following doesn't work because the returns are out of scope to the exampleFunc()

```
function exampleFunc() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://example.com/page',
    success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){
      return true;
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      return false;
    }
  });
}
```

I Googled for a solution and believe I should be doing a callback but couldn't seems to achieve the desired outcome.

**Edit:** Te be more specific I require the function to return true or false because my use case currently has me doing :

```
if (exampleFunc()) { 
  // run this code
}
```

Comment: The code you posted are meant for this purpose...success and error are your callback functions. Maybe your problem lies somewhere else? If you want the method to return true of false, assign it to a variable that is outside the $.ajax scope.

Answer (score 2):

You can't return from something asynchronous. The callback function has to do what you want to do in a forwards direction.

Answer (score 1):

Simply pass the function to your `exampleFunc()` and call it in your ajax success callback.

```
// you want this function to be run on ajax success.
function sayHello() {
   alert('hello'); 
}

function exampleFunc(callback) {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://example.com/page',
    success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){
      if (callback && typeof callback == 'function') {
         callback() // here, you call sayHello, which is passed as parameter
      }
      return true;
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      return false;
    }
  });
}

exampleFun(sayHello); // start ajax
```

Comment: Your code won't work unless your pass `sayHello` to `exampleFun`

Comment: Welcome, btw, do you really need to wrap your callback function?

Answer (score 0):

```
function exampleFunc() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://example.com/page',
    async: false,
    success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){
      return true;
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      return false;
    }
  });
}
```

Notice `async: false`

Answer (score 0):

`$.ajax` is an asynchronous call which will have a callback handler on success/error response. To work around, you need to pass a callback.

```
function exampleFunc(callback, errorCallback) {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://example.com/page',
    success: callback,
    error: errorCallback
  });
}
```

### USAGE

```
exampleFunc(function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
      // do whatever you want, you have got a success response
      //return true;
    }, function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      // error occured, show some red error box
      //return false;
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

This can only be done if you got a sync function like:

```
function exampleFunc() {
  var success;
  $.ajax({
    async : false,
    url: 'http://example.com/page',
    success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){
      success= true;
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      success= false;
    }
  });
  return success;
}
```

What you can do is pass a function to your function. Something like:

```
var hello = "Hello World";
exampleFunc(function(){
    alert(hello); // Alerts Hello World on success
},
function(){
    alert("FAILED"); // Alerts FAILED on error
});
```

And the function will look like:

```
function exampleFunc(success, error) {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://example.com/page',
    success: success,
    error: error
  });
}
```

But you can't change the `hello` var inside the function and use it after the function call. Because the call's keep async.

Comment: -1 - this will always return `undefined` as ajax call is still async

Comment: Sorry, you have added `async : false` which will work. It's still a poor idea to hang your browser until response.

Comment: I changed it directly after I posted because I saw I missed it. It's not the best way to handle, that's why I gave an alternative option.